# C99 Variable Length Array Max sizes and sizeof Function

Tags: c, c99, variable-length-array

I am experimenting with the use of Variable Length Arrays (VLAs) in my C code and trying to iron out my understanding of what they should and shouldn't do.

I have the following snippet from my function:

```
void get_pdw_frame_usb(pdws_t *pdw_frame, pdw_io_t *pdw_io)
{
...
unsigned char buf[pdw_io->packet_size];
unsigned char *pdw_buf;
memset(buf, '\0', sizeof(buf));
```

`pdw_io` is a data structure containing, amongst other things, `packet_size`, which is of type `size_t`

the char array `buf` is to be used to store the contents of a usb bulk transfer packet

I'm trying to instantiate it here as an automatic variable using the C99 VLA approach. I'm then trying to ensure its contents are all zeros.

I'm having a few issues.

Firstly, if `pdw_io->packet_size` is set to 8 (quite small), then buf is set to a reasonable looking value, i.e. debugging with gdb i can inspect it as follows:

```
(gdb) p buf
$27 = 0xbffe5be8 "\270", <incomplete sequence \370\267>
```

If `pdw_io->packet_size` is set to 12008 (fair bit larger), then I get the following which doesn't look so good:

```
(gdb) p buf
$29 = 0xbffe2d08 ""
```

Is 12008 chars too large for a VLA? Or perhaps that gdb output is not something to worry about, it just looks a bit like it hasn't allocated anything to me?

Also when inspecting the size of `buf` I get the following in both cases:

```
(gdb) p sizeof(buf)
$30 = 0
```

which I would have expected to be 8 in the 1st instance and 12008 in the 2nd

Am I wrong in thinking it should be possible to use the `sizeof` function in this way with a VLA?

My problem is that the subsequent usb bulk transfer is failing and I want to try and rule out the fact it may have something to do with my use of VLAs, which are a bit of a new area for me..

UPDATE

Wrote the following minimal, complete and hopefully verifiable program to try and confirm my observations:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void test_vla(size_t n)
{
    unsigned char buf[n];
    printf("sizeof buf = %zu\n", sizeof buf);    
}

int main()
{
    test_vla(12008);
    return 0;
}
```

now if I break on the `printf` statement with gdb and run `p sizeof buf` I get 0 but `printf` outputs 12008.

`gdb` version is:

```
(gdb) show version
GNU gdb (Ubuntu 7.7.1-0ubuntu5~14.04.2) 7.7.1
```

Comment: Whenever you need to allocate large amounts of memory, you should do so on the heap.

Comment: Whichb value has `pdw_io->packet_size`?

Comment: is 12008 bytes large?

Comment: @Lundin: Unless OP has many such buffers in nested function calls, there is no problem here. (Although he would be better off with the heap).

Comment: @Olaf  Nothing nothing ,calculation mistake .

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: I would consider `malloc` if I need memory more than few hundred bytes . So according to me `12008` is pretty good reason to use `malloc` or similar .

Comment: @ameyCU: AFAIK Linux has a default stack size of 8MiB. So that is pretty sufficient. Presuming this is not an AVR, PIC, etc., of course. OTOH, on such systems you should not use `malloc` either.

Comment: come on olaf - its all 3 of those.. I'm worried about declaring the VLA and whether I can get its size, I've provided the declaration statement and 2 example arguments for that statement, I've then shown the subsequent variable values from gdb, and also the values returned by sizeof

Comment: @Olaf  Ofcourse using `malloc` wont guarantee memory allocation but atlest an indication will be there .

Comment: yes the platform is a linux PC, so hoping 12k on the stack is not too outrageous - there is only the single buffer, not multiples in nested function calls..

Comment: Note that a compiler doesn't need to support VLA:s to be compatible with C11. This means that VLA:s should be avoided for portability reasons and that they will probably be removed in future C standards.

Comment: would I be right in thinking if it is unsupported then the compiler would complain of a syntax error? I take the portability point. I think my compiler supports the feature (gcc (Ubuntu 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04) 4.8.4)

Comment: When you say "I get the following which doesn't look so good", what do you mean? It looks fine to me. Also, the sizeof printing 0 is probably a gdb issue, you should print it in your program instead.

Comment: @KlasLindbäck: The question is tagged C99 which requires VLA support. C11 made a step backwards by making it optional (for whatever stupid reason). And removal is not likely and not listed in the future directions in the standard. Do you have any indication for this claim?

Comment: @interjay yes I'm not sure how to interpret it, maybe it is fine, but I was half expecting to see something similar for when packet_size was 12008 as for when it was 8, i.e. a few random chars and that incomplete-sequence text (note I inspected buf prior to the memset call). Good shout on printing sizeof in the program as well.. will try that now..

Comment: 1) you are using C99 (according to the tag, so the comment does not apply. 2) there is no indication it will become non-standard. 3) Yes, the compiler shall complain, because the compiler cannot generate code if it does not support VLAs.

Comment: @bph gdb prints a char array as a zero-terminated string, so all that output tells you is that the first character is zero. I don't think you have an actual issue here.

Comment: You still did not state which value `pdw_io->packet_size` **actually** has.

Comment: @interjay very useful, i did not realise that - thankyou

Comment: Are these the values from the debugger at the location you get the `sizeof` the VLA or do you just presume? Note that the VLA might just come to life with the call to `memset`.

Comment: `p sizeof(buf)` giving `0` after `char buf[something];` indicates `something` equals `0`.

Comment: @alk: Exactly my point.

Comment: @alk: No, it indicates that gdb doesn't know how to use `sizeof` with a VLA operand. It should be checked in the code.

Comment: Seeing `$27 = 0xbffe5be8 "\270", <incomplete sequence \370\267>` after a `memset(buf, '\0', something);` indicates as well `something` being equal `0`.

Comment: @Olaf I stepped through the program once with pdw_io->packet_size set to 8 and then again with it set to 12008. Immediately after stepping past the 'unsigned char buf[pdw_io->packet_size];' statement I inspected buf in gdb, i.e. p buf with output shown in OP. I also checked the sizeof(buf) in the same way at this point for both packet_size values, again output in OP. I think interjay has explained my error with using p sizeof in gdb. I'm still not 100% sure whether the VLA has been successful for packet_size of 12008

Comment: @interjay: Yes, you are correct! The code needs to evaluate this, my bad. The debugger fails on this. (leaving my wrong comment, the 1st, as the 2nd stands :-))

Comment: What is so complicated or unclear about my request? As you state `sizeof(buf) == 0`, it 1) apparently exists at that time, but it's size is `0`, you hae to check `pdw_io->packet_size`. I'm not a native speaker, but I'm very sure I have asked clearly enough.

Comment: @alk - yes, that is similar, I should perhaps have asked 2 separate questions, one about the max size of a VLA and another about use of sizeof in gdb w.r.t a VLA

Comment: @Olaf are you addressing me or alk or interjay? maybe use the @ terminology? I am setting the value of pdw_io->packet_size in the 1st instance to 8 and in the 2nd instance to 12008. By 'Instance' I mean 'run' in gdb - hope that clears things up?

Comment: As the OP gets the notification anyway, I apparently addressed you. However, apparently there is no way to make you understand what I mean or you insist on missunderstanding me. I'm out of this remote debugging session.

Comment: Your update doesn't use a VLA, so of course it doesn't trigger the problem. Older versions of gdb don't support `sizeof` on VLAs; newer versions do. See my updated answer.

Comment: sorry of course! I am an idiot.. reworking it now and will check your update

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem you're running into is a bug (or perhaps more accurately a missing feature) in `gdb`.  `gdb` does not correctly handle the `sizeof` operator applied to a VLA (variable-length array).

[This message](http://www.sourceware.org/ml/gdb-patches/2013-11/msg00631.html) from a gdb mailing list indicates that support for `sizeof` on VLAs has been implemented in `gdb`, but only relatively recently.  Apparently it isn't in the version you and I are both using (gdb 7.7.1).  Without that fix, it incorrectly prints the size of a VLA as 0.  Your code itself should behave correctly; it's just `gdb` that isn't handling it properly.

There's nothing particularly wrong with your code, as long as (a) it's compiled with a compiler that supports VLAs, and (b) the size of the array is positive and not too large.  (VLAs are not supported in C90, except perhaps as an extension, were introduced as a standard feature in C99, and were made optional in C11.)

A possible workaround is to modify your program to save the value of `sizeof vla` to a variable that you can then print from `gdb`.

Another problem with `gdb` is that printing the VLA object itself behaves differently than printing a fixed-size array object.  It apparently treats a VLA as a pointer to its first element rather than as an array object.

Here's a `gdb` transcript that illustrates the problem:

```
GNU gdb (Ubuntu 7.7.1-0ubuntu5~14.04.2) 7.7.1
[SNIP]
(gdb) list
1       #include <stdio.h>
2       #include <string.h>
3       int main(void) {
4           int len = 6;
5           char vla[len];
6           const size_t vla_size = sizeof vla;
7           char arr[6];
8           strcpy(vla, "hello");
9           strcpy(arr, "world");
10      }
(gdb) break 10
Breakpoint 1 at 0x400600: file c.c, line 10.
(gdb) run
Starting program: /home/kst/c 

Breakpoint 1, main () at c.c:10
10      }
(gdb) print sizeof vla
$1 = 0
(gdb) print vla_size
$2 = 6
(gdb) print sizeof arr
$3 = 6
(gdb) print vla
$4 = 0x7fffffffdc10 "hello"
(gdb) print arr
$5 = "world"
(gdb) print arr+0
$6 = 0x7fffffffdc40 "world"
(gdb) continue
Continuing.
[Inferior 1 (process 28430) exited normally]
(gdb) quit
```

> Is 12008 chars too large for a VLA?

Probably not. For most implementations, a VLA can be just as large as a fixed-size array. There's no real difference (in terms of memory allocation) between:

```
{
    int size = 12008;
    char buf[size];
}
```

and

```
{
    int buf[12008];
}
```

Many systems limit the amount of memory you can allocate on the stack, but a 12008-byte array isn't likely to push those limits.

Still, if you're going to be allocating large arrays, it's probably better to do so via `malloc()` (which means you'll need to explicitly call `free()` for each allocated object).

Comment: I just ran the code through gdb with pdw_io->packet_size set to 8. the prinf statement output 8, and p sizeof(buf) from the gdb prompt output 0. So I'm happy that my VLA is working as expected, I was just wrong to assume that running p sizeof(buf) would give me the same result. I just ran it with pdw_io->packet_size set to 12008 as well and the printf output 12008 and gdb output 0, so the same behaviour. Thats great so I know the VLA is working fine for a size of 12008 bytes - my problem must lie elsewhere so back to the drawing board..